# Add Attachment to a custom form in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I want to add a field in Orchard custom form so user can use it to upload a file with certain document type and size.

I've tried the following modules but nothing appears when adding a new field:

1. File Field - Version: 1.2
2. Media Picker Field - Version: 1.2
3. Ajax File Uploader - Version: 1.5.1
4. CloudConstruct.SecureFileField - Version: 1.4

Please help.

**Update:**

**I've managed to implement IStorageProvider by myself but still the file uploaded with 0 KB size, please find cose snippet [link](https://gist.github.com/EmadMokhtar/be6ab66fdddca4fbca0f)**

Comment: I think they all are incompatible with the newest Orchard versions. I managed with very little effort to make the File Field working with Orchard 1.8. Just replace the deprecated IMediaService with IStorageProvider in the FileFieldDriver class, while tweaking a little bit by looking at the IStorageProvider's implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-implement it and publish it on [GitHub](https://github.com/EmadMokhtar/Contrib.FileField)